# How to write own scaffolder (like RoR has?)

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, node.js, bash

I would like to create own scaffolder for websites, something like Ruby On Rails has:

```
rails g modelname fieldlist
```

But for my own purposes - it should generate HTML, CSS and JavaScript files in proper folders (folder paths will be taken from configuration file) with specific content.

My question is: which language (or tool) is the best for such task?

I was trying to write that using `bash` but codebase became quick very large and messy.

My target is unix platforms (especially Linux) - I'm thinking about Ruby or Python, but can I achieve such task with e.g. JavaScript/node?

Are there tools for something like that? I've heard something about Yeoman but I'm not sure if it is capable for my problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Well since your question is too broad and you seem to be looking for a website generator, at least for Ruby here are the most obvious choices:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation

All of them use templates, which I assume that will be usefull.

One of the most popular choice is the [jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll), which powers [github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/)

If none of them work for you, you can investigate their source code to create your own solution.

If you are going the rails way there's [rails apps composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer)

Comment: no, I said I want own scaffolder *FOR* websites - not websites themselves. And I'm looking for a programming tools to create it - like You've written - I'll take a look inside nanoc (it's jekyll alternative that I know better) but I think they have too much feature already that I don't need (I would prefer to start from zero)